# How to convert ppi to android dpi

Tags: android

Can anyone help me.
I need to convert ppi to android device dpi.
I have gone through some other post in stack overflow but i didnt get the exact answer.

Why iam asking this question is, now iam developing an android app ,when i tested that app in a real device(Samsung Galaxy Grand) it's not good to see the app interface,but when i created an emulator with screen configuration of samsung galaxy grand the app interface is perfect as what i need.

> **Screen Configuration used in emulator** 
>    screen Size:5 inch
>    Resolution :800 x 480
>    Aspect Ratio: long
>    Size :normal(also tested large)
>    Density: hdpi,mdpi

please anyone help in this issue please
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I hope this information will be useful
http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/#dimension-units
http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/steven-byle/understanding-density-independence-android

Comment: Nope. Doesn’t address the question.